interacting with specific labels with specific buttons tkinter
I'm trying to make a simple initiative tracker for my group's D&D game because we have quite a few players. So far it functions, a player had the idea for a button to remove things from the initiative once they die.
Right now the relevant part is that I make 2 labels per row: Name and Initiative.
Where I am: Buttons do nothing
enter image description here
def create_initiative_window(sorted_dict):
    initiative_window=tkinter.Toplevel(parent_window)
    initiative_window.minsize(200,200)
    initiative_window.title("Initiative rolled!")
    initiatives_list = []
    current_row = 1
    for each in reversed(sorted_dict):
        new_label = tkinter.Label(initiative_window,text= f"    {each[0]}", font=("Arial",12), anchor="w")
        new_label.grid(sticky= "w",column=1, row=current_row)
        initiatives_list.append(new_label)
        kill_button = tkinter.Button(initiative_window, text = "Kill", command= lambda: strikethrough(initiatives_list,current_row-2))
        kill_button.grid(sticky="e", column = 3, row=current_row)

        current_row += 1
    current_row= 1

Striking the labels out using .join or destroying them individually would be an acceptable outcome, I just can't quite figure out how to reference a tkinter.Label using a tkinter.Button with a command, because I need each line to have their own button and they're generated newly each time the window is created so they're dynamic.
Another option would be any suggestion of different widgets for this purpose?
